# adapter.add() crashes application

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listitem

I have  problem  with the adapter.add() method. It causes my app to crash.

My MainActivity is here:

```
 package com.example.olev.shoppinglist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<String>productNames=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


public void addNewProduct(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,AddProduct.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addToList();
    ListView productList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.productList);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,productNames);

   productList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void addToList(){
    Bundle itemData=getIntent().getExtras();

    if(itemData==null){
        return ;
    }
    String product=itemData.getString("product");
    productNames.add(product);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




}
```

also my AddProduct:

```
package com.example.olev.shoppinglist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;




public class AddProduct extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_product);
}

public void sendProductToMain(View view){
    EditText productName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.productName);
    String product= productName.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent (this,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("product",product);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_item, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Other than that im using CustomAdapter which extends ArrayAdapter.

My problem is that if I run this code like it is, I can add item to listview, but as I try to add another one the first one gets overwritten. So I have only one item all the time. If I remove comment on line adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); the app crashes when reaching to this line.

I have also tried  adapter.add(product); The result is the same as the line above - app crashes.

I have searched for answer in here, but can't find it.

My question is how to fix it so that I could dynamically add item to ListView??

**EDIT:**

The error message im getting

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.olev.shoppinglist/com.example.olev.shoppinglist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.olev.shoppinglist.MainActivity.addToList(MainActivity.java:48)
            at com.example.olev.shoppinglist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: You need to post the stack trace of the exception. Just saying "crash" doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are sending String in place of List from your first activity to another activity.
i.e. Suppose the line putExtra("product","Item1") is for sending a string item item1 in your second activity. When you call your second activity, list is intialized again and only one item i.e. "Item1" is added to the list.

To send list, you can use intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key",value); method.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77303/discussion-on-answer-by-mohit-rajput-adapter-add-crashes-application).